# MatDatepicker in Angular Library

Tags: angular, angular-library

Is it possible to use MatDatepicker without importing it in the root of application as error saing:

```
ERROR Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom implementation.
```

Because I want to use it just when Angular Library is imported. For this purpose Angular Libraries was created for.

When I imported MatMomentDateModule and MatNativeDateModule in the root of application, error is gone. But as I said I want to import it in Angular library.

Comment: can you use standdalone components?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to import it in Angular library"? Could you share an example of what you are trying to do

Comment: "What do you mean" - https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries, I want to import any 3rd party module, inside of Angular library

Comment: "can you use standdalone components?" - Yes, you are right, I'm using standalone component, but by mistake I'm trying to import modules into the main library module, not to the standalone component, so I added required imports into component, and everething works. Thank you bro!